# When is $\mathrm{Hom}(i(x), y)\to\mathrm{Hom}(f(x),\mathrm{Lan}_i(f)(y))$ an isomorphism?

Tags: category-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}\DeclareMathOperator{\Nat}{Nat}$
Let $i : A\to B$ and $f : A\to C$ be functors.

In the case where $A=C$ and $f$ is the identity functor, if the left Kan extension of $f$ along $i$ is pointwise, then it is a right adjoint to $i$.
In general, we can build a transformation
$$\mathrm{Hom}(i(x), y)\to \mathrm{Hom}(f(x),\mathrm{Lan}_i(f)(y))$$
natural in $x$ and $y$ that specializes to the adjunction in the case of the previous sentence. In general, this transformation only have an initial property (it is a translation of the initial property of $\mathrm{Lan}_i(f)$) and is not an isomorphism.

An other case where it is an isomorphism arises when we consider the [nerve](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve+and+realization) of some functor $F : A→B$. It is the left Kan extension of the Yoneda embedding $A\to [A^{\mathrm{op}},\mathrm{Set}]$ along $F$. The Yoneda lemma says that the morphism above is an isomorphism.

> **Question:** Is there something interesting to say about when this morphism is an isomorphism? Some necessary or sufficient condition? (Maybe nothing?)

---

I add more details below.

**Construction of the morphism.** The Yoneda lemma imply that for any functor $g : B→C$ (and as above $i:A\to B$ and $f:A\to C$), the set of natural transformations $f\to g\circ i$ is in natural bijection with the natural transformations
$$\mathrm{Hom}(i(x), y)\to \mathrm{Hom}(f(x),g(y))\text{.}$$
We can use the end/coend calculus for this:
$$\begin{align*}
\Nat(f,g\circ i) &\cong \int_x \Hom(f(x), g(i(x)))\\
&\cong \int_x \Hom\left[f(x), ∫_y g(y)^{\Hom(i(x),y)}\right]\\
&\cong ∫_{x,y} \Hom[\Hom(i(x),y), \Hom(f(x),g(y))]
\end{align*}$$

Thus a Kan extension can equally be defined using the morphism this question is about.

There is no implication between "$f\to g\circ i$ is an isomorphism" and the property that the corresponding morphism on the other side is an isomorphism (when $g = \mathrm{Lan}_i(f)$). Indeed, in the case of the nerve functor, $f\to g\circ i$ is not an isomorphism. And in the case of the realization functor, $f\to g\circ i$ is an isomorphism but the corresponding transformation is not.

I would enjoy an answer involving profunctors to explain how the "bending" works and what corresponds to what (a bit like we can do with the units/counit of an adjunction to make correspond the zig-zag identities with the property that the two natural transformations are inverses).

Comment: compositition symbol $\circ$: `\circ`, right arrow $\to$: `\to` or `\rightarrow`, $\cong$: `\cong`; please see edits so you can improve your formatting. $\int$: `\int`

Comment: @amWhy Ok, thank you. I'll do that in the future but I see no difference on my computer between `\cong` ($\cong$) and `≅` ($≅$). I imagine there is one on yours. By the way I just put back "counit", you replaced it by "count".

Comment: What you pasted looked like $\cong$, so I used the corresponding LaTeX symbol.  If you meant to use $\equiv$, then use `\equiv`. Copy and pastes of text symbols deteriorate more easily, and may not be seen consistently by all users.  Also, know that I would not "nitpick" if you hadn't already seemed to exhibit some competence in formatting.  I thought you might appreciate the pointers.

Comment: @amWhy Actually I used unicode characters instead of latex commands intentionally, because I have easy access to them on my keyboard and know mathjax supports them (I don't copy/paste! It would be easier to type the latex.). I found some discussions about this issue on the meta: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22630/) and [there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29988/). But anyway it's not important.

Answer (score 0):

This post on MO seems to answer my question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252383/the-kan-construction-profunctors-and-kan-extensions. It takes into account both the situations in the OP.

I yet have to read it and will edit this answer when I do if nobody posts an other answer meanwhile.

Comment: I plan to edit when I have time.